# Replace option value text from select with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to replace the text English from option value with javascript. Code is next:

```
<div>
<select name="input_14" id="input_29_14">
<option value="English">English</option>
</select>
</div>
```

So this is what I tried:

```
document.querySelector("div.selector option[value=English]").text = "Inglés";
```

But it doesn't change the text. Anyone can provide me an alternative function?

Thank you

Comment: Your div has no class so `div.selector` won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query selector to

```
document.querySelector("option[value=English]").text = "Inglés";
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, so how can I replace the text in another selector? I mean, this is replacing the text in one, but I have another dropdown box where the 'English' text appears and is not being replaced.

Comment: @Robertoss please share sample code with me.

Comment: is same code than above, just changes select id: <select name="input_14" id="input_29_91">

Comment: Hi, do you have any update for this? I just need to make this available to when English shows for second time.

Comment: @Robertoss 
HTML:
`<div>
<select name="input_14" id="input_29_14">
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="English">English</option>
</select>
</div>`

JS: 
`const elements = document.querySelectorAll("option[value=English]");
const length = elements.length;

for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i)
 elements[i].text = 'Inglés';`

Comment: Thank you! this works but there seems to be a conflict, I'm trying to apply same query to more than one option value.. so if I add this: const elements = document.querySelectorAll("option[value=Spanish]"); const length = elements.length; for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) elements[i].text = 'Español'; under the English option, it doesn't work. How can it be solved?

Comment: ok I solved this situation with JQuery directly: jQuery("option[value=Spanish]").text("Español");

Answer (score 1):

The reason your current code is not working is because `div.selector` is looking for a div with the class **selector**.

Just add an id to the option, get the id with JavaScript and change to whatever you want.

```js
document.getElementById("lang").text = "Anglais";
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="input_14" id="input_29_14">
    <option id="lang" value="English">English</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with jQuery:

```
jQuery("option[value=English]").text("Inglés");
```